# Obter coordenadas de uma rodovia no Brasil

Tags: google-maps, maps

Como posso obter todas as coordenadas de uma determinada rodovia brasileira? Estou iniciando uma pesquisa e não consegui encontrar material que me ajudasse nesta tarefa. Basicamente eu preciso identificar por exemplo: A latitude e longitude do kilômetro 120 na BR 040. Obrigado.

Comment: Da uma olhada na google API directions: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Renan, tente detalhar melhor sua dúvida. Quais tecnologias você está utilizando? O que você já tem pronto?

Comment: Meu objetivo é criar uma aplicação Android que irá exibir um mapa e preciso que cada Km da rodovia esteja associado a uma coordenada, no primeiro momento eu preciso apenas criar uma base de dados com essas coordenadas, posteriormente irei exportar essa base para minha aplicação Android.